# Error al insertar columna en sqlite

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, webservice

Buenas tardes

Estoy insertando datos que obtengo de un webservices a mi base datos sqlite solo que al momento ejecutar mi app me dice que una columna no existe en tabla

Ya he cambia el nombre de la base de datos, de version pero sigue el error

Error

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) table clienteon has no column named ClienteClave

Dejo código

```
public void insertcliente(int Empresa,
                              int Cliente,
                              String ClienteClave)
    {
        Object[] Data = {Empresa,Cliente,ClienteClave};
        executeSQL("INSERT INTO " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME + "(" + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Empresa + "," + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Cliente + "," + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion  + ") VALUES(?,?,?)", Data );
}


public static class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DBManager";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "hugo.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "clienteon";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Empresa = "Empresa";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Cliente = "Cliente";
    //public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ClienteClave = "ClienteClave";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion = "ClienteDescripcion";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Moneda = "Moneda";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Proveedor = "Proveedor";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ProveedorDescripcion = "ProveedorDescripcion";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Saldo = "Saldo";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SaldoVencido = "SaldoVencido";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DatosGenerales = "DatosGenerales";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PRUEBA = "PRUEBA";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w("[CHECK]", "DBHelper.onCreate....");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME + "("
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Empresa + " TEXT ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Cliente + " TEXT "
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion + "TEXT "
                + ");");

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        Log.w(TAG, "Actualizacion de BDD de la version " + oldVersion + " a la "
                + newVersion + ", de la que se destruira la informacion anterior");

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(db);

    }

    DBhelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
}

  public STR_Resultado Clientes(int _Documento)
    {


    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(ONControlWSNameSpace, "CXCPSaldoDocumento");
    request.addProperty("Empresa",ONControlEmpresa);
    request.addProperty("Token",ONControlToken);
    request.addProperty("Documento",_Documento);
    request.addProperty("Cliente", "0");
    request.addProperty("Proveedor", "0");
    request.addProperty("Moneda", "0");
    request.addProperty("Zona", ONControlZonaCliente);
    request.addProperty("Filtro", "E");
    request.addProperty("FiltroAdicional", " ");
    // Property which holds input parameters

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes = false;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(ONControlWSURL, 7000);

    STR_Resultado O_Resultado = new STR_Resultado();


    O_Resultado.ClienteArray = new ArrayList();

    //ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayadapter;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(ONControlWSNameSpace+"CXCPSaldoDocumento", envelope);

        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        O_Resultado.ErrorId= Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
        O_Resultado.UltimoId= Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(1).toString());
        O_Resultado.Mensaje= String.valueOf(response.getProperty(2));


        SoapObject SO_CXCPClienteProveedor = (SoapObject)((SoapObject)((SoapObject)((SoapObject) envelope.getResponse()).getProperty(3)).getProperty(1)).getProperty(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < SO_CXCPClienteProveedor.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

            Clientes.oBD.insertcliente(ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(webService.WSGetPropertyNull("Empresa", (SoapObject) SO_CXCPClienteProveedor.getProperty(i))),
                                         ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(webService.WSGetPropertyNull("Cliente", (SoapObject) SO_CXCPClienteProveedor.getProperty(i))),
                                         webService.WSGetPropertyNull("ClienteClave", (SoapObject) SO_CXCPClienteProveedor.getProperty(i)));




        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return O_Resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.w("[CHECK]", "DBHelper.onCreate....");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Empresa + " TEXT , "
            + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Cliente + " TEXT, "
            + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion + " TEXT, "
            + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteClave + " TEXT "
            + ");");}
```

Veo que tienes comentada tu variable COLUMN_NAME_ClienteClave, ademas que en la creación de la tabla no estas indicando que se cree.

Answer (score 0):

El método `onCreate()` es usado para crear la estructura de las tablas al crearse tu aplicación,  el error indica que no existe una columna `ClienteClave` en tu tabla `clienteon`

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) table clienteon has no column named ClienteClave

Los campos necesarios al insertar son `Empresa`, `Cliente` y `ClienteClave`:

```
Clientes.oBD.insertcliente(ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(webService.WSGetPropertyNull("Empresa", (SoapObject) SO_CXCPClienteProveedor.getProperty(i))),
                                         ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(webService.WSGetPropertyNull("Cliente", (SoapObject) SO_CXCPClienteProveedor.getProperty(i))),
                                         webService.WSGetPropertyNull("ClienteClave", (SoapObject) SO_CXCPClienteProveedor.getProperty(i)));
```

para esto agrega el campo necesario, y asegura agregar una "," entre la definición de cada campo:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.w("[CHECK]", "DBHelper.onCreate....");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Empresa + " TEXT ,"
            + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Cliente + " TEXT, "
           /*+ DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion + "TEXT, "*/
            + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteClave + " TEXT "
            + ");");

}
```

**pero es importante elimines la aplicación porque seguirá marcando el error ya que tienes creada una base de datos con una tabla con la estructura anterior que es incorrecta.**